# Setting style of Quick Launch Navigation with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, navigation, pnp-powershell, modern-experience

I have been searching for a while but did not find anything. How can I set the style of the quick launch navigation via PowerShell?

I want to configure it from mega-menu to overlapping.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") | Out-Null

$webUrl = "<site url>"
$username = "<username>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com"
$pw = read-host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString

$ctx= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webURL)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$pw)
$ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$ctx.Web.MegaMenuEnabled = $false //Disables megamenu experience
$ctx.Web.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

**OR**: Using PnP PowerShel:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url <yoursite>
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$web.MegaMenuEnabled = $false //$false to disable, $true to enable
$web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

**Source**: [Manage SharePoint communication site megamenu with CSOM and PowerShell](https://mattipaukkonen.com/2018/08/22/manage-sharepoint-communication-sites-megamenu-with-csom-and-powershell/)

You can also use [Set-PnPWeb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpweb) command to set `MegaMenuEnabled` parameter of SharePoint web.

Comment: Thank you, that's it!